# Как открыть таблицу excel в DataGridView C# Winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, excel, datagridview

Есть таблица Excel, необходимо экспортировать файлы из неё в DataGridView. Как это можно сделать? Нашёл единственный гайд на ютубе, который у меня не работает, т. к. требуется переставить конфигурацию на x86, после чего привязання база данных не будет работать. Как можно реализовать подобную функцию?